# Acceleration Issues

Tags: acceleration, mahindra

I have acceleration issues with my Mahindra Bolero SLX.

Acceleration fails/drops all of a sudden while driving. When this occurs I pull off from the pedal and pump a little bit and it becomes okay for sometime.

What could be the main reason behind this issue?

Comment: I'm in the States and I had a similar problem on my Toyota Corolla and I swear it was the cheap gas I was putting in it.  I switched to only Top Tier Gas, https://www.toptiergas.com/, and it seemed to clear up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be some problems, but try simple things first, not sure about this car but if it is gasoline check your spark plugs, ignition coils and cables, if they are ok, check if inyectors are firing, put a long flat head screwdriver in the base of the inyector and the other side where is the handle touch it with your hear, if you listen to a constant sound they are ok, if is intermitent, is a problem with your inyector or the wiring that controls it or your computer if it is a diesel probably is a malfuction of the acelerator pedal position sensor( not sure if it is call like that) that it isn't sending the correct lecture of the amount of diesel should be inyected, causing it to lose its acceleration